# How would I schedule a task after certain number of minutes in Python efficiently?

Tags: python, time, schedule

How would I schedule a task after a certain number of minutes?
example:

```py
schedule(32).do(job) # number of minutes, and random function to execute
```

I looked into time.sleep and scheduler but I heard time.sleep was not the best way do deal with these types of situations and scheduler repeats the job

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach by getting time after `n` mins

**Ex:**

```
import schedule
import datetime

def job():
    print('Hello')
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
    
    
def get_mins(m):
    return (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=m)).strftime("%H:%M")

t = get_mins(1)   # Get time after n mins.
print(t)
schedule.every().day.at(t).do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using libraries shipped with Python and using seconds just to make the demo faster.

`schedule` takes a time and a function and starts a thread that sleeps for that time and then calls the function:

```py
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime

def _schedule_worker(seconds,function):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    function()

def schedule(seconds,function):
    threading.Thread(target=_schedule_worker,args=(seconds,function)).start()

def work():
    print(datetime.now())

print(datetime.now())
schedule(1,work)
schedule(5,work)
schedule(8,work)
schedule(10,work)
```

Output:

```
2021-04-04 23:30:08.916058
2021-04-04 23:30:09.926058
2021-04-04 23:30:13.933824
2021-04-04 23:30:16.923825
2021-04-04 23:30:18.923826
```